# Objective c "UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)self.view;" convention

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came upon an objective-c line in my book on IOS and it has a certain format that I've never seen before. It would be nice if someone could tell me what the line means and any other thing I should know about the convention.

So here's the method the line is in:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   //we must cast the view to UIImageView so the compiler knows is is okay
   //to send it setImage

   UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) self.view; //<----the line I'm concerned with
   imageView.image = self.image;
}
```

In case you didn't notice, the line I'm concerned with is the

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) self.view;
```

line.

Comment: What part of that line don't you understand? Be specific.

Comment: In your code, right above the line you're concerned with, there is a comment that explains what this line does: it declares that `self.view` is an `UIImageView` object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple cast from one type to another.  Remove the (UIImageView* *) on the right hand side and you will get a warning saying "Incompatible pointer types initializing UIImageView* with an expression of type UIView *".  This happens because self.view is a UIView and while UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, it is not a UIView.  The compiler will simply warn you that they are different types and by casting it your telling the compiler to treat self.view like a UIImageView.  It's like when your noisy dog barks when your friends come to your door and you say "calm down bessy, he's a good person, you can go lay back down now".